# How to make a proper OAuth request to Dataverse API with Postman?

Tags: azure, rest, power-automate, dataverse

I want to make an *OAth* request to the *Microsoft Dataverse API* to get the Bearer token, and with this token I wish to make authenticated requests to PowerAutomate. I use Postman for making the requests. I can get the Bearer token in 2 different ways, but with the same result after using these in a request: **401 Unauthorized**

My settings:

Common auth url:
[image]

Auth url with TenantID:
[image]

As you can see I got a Bearer token for both, but when I try to call the simplest */WhoAmI* endpoint I got 401 Unathorized error.

I have my API permissions set up properly in the Azure app:
[image]

I have my application user with the right application ID:
[image]

My first question: **What am I missing? What else should I set up?**

My second question: **What is the difference between the two auth endpoint I am using?**

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: are you working off some documentation? it'd be helpful to include that here.

Comment: You are right @DerekGusoff, a documentation would be great, I will include it here if I will have one. Feel free to ask any question, that helps creating the documentation too.

Comment: no, I mean are you *using* some documentation? Like, how did you know this was the way to set up the API permissions.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one **multitenant** Azure AD application and added `API permissions` like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow same as you via Postman like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
scope: https://org25xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/.default
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call **`/WhoAmI`** endpoint, I too got **401 Unauthorized** error like below:

```
GET https://org25bexxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/WhoamI
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got the **same error** when I used access token generated with **`common`** auth URL too.

> To **resolve** the error, try using **`implicit flow`** to generate
> access token.

Make sure to enable *“oauth2AllowImplicitFlow*” property in app's **Manifest** file before generating token like below:

[image]

Now, create new **environment** in Postman with below parameters:

```http
url: <your Dynamics 365 URL>
clientid: <appID of Azure AD application>
version: 9.0
webapiurl: {{url}}/api/data/v{{version}}/
callback: <redirect URL of Azure AD app>
authurl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource={{url}}
```

[image]

To generate access token, open new tab and select **`OAuth 2.0`** in Authorization tab by entering details like this:

[image]

After selecting `Get New Access Token` option, I signed in with admin credentials and got **access token** successfully like below:

[image]

I selected **Use token** option and called **`/WhoAmI`** endpoint where I got **results** successfully like below:

```
GET {{webapiurl}}WhoAmI
```

**Response:**

[image]

> What is the difference between the two auth endpoint I am using?

**Common Auth URL:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token is a **common** endpoint used to get token for any Azure AD tenant. If your application is multi-tenant, then your **token endpoint** will be common like below:

[image]

**Auth URL with TenantID:**
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/token) is used to get token for particular tenant ID. If your application is single tenant, then your **token endpoint** will be with `tenantID` like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Postman tool to test Dynamics 365 online Web API by **Rajeev Pentyala**](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2019/02/13/step-by-step-postman-tool-to-test-dynamics-365-online-web-api/)

Comment: Thank you @Sridevi it works, BUT after sending the authorization request I got a prompt window where I have to login. That I can do when I use Postman, but I want to achieve the same behavior with programmed REST calls in Java. So my question is: Is there a way to request a Bearer token without having to log into my Microsoft account? For example using secrets?

Comment: To work with **Delegated** permissions, you need to generate access token using **delegated** flows like implicit flow, authorization code flow etc..... that involves user interaction. You can generate token without signing in as user by passing secret(client credentials) BUT you cannot call API with those tokens that gives you `401 Unauthorized` error.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make use of [**ROPC** flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) that generates bearer token without logging in. But you need to include user's UPN and `password` in request parameters to fetch token.

Comment: thank you ROPC flow is what I am looking for, but still missing something, because my own user uses two-factor authentication, which obviously makes this impossible to use, and I don't know what is the application user's credentials and where to find it. I will give myself a few days, if I don't find a better solution I will mark yours as a solution.